# Getting error in get(relativePosition) when I replace ArrayList<String> with String type

Tags: java, android

I have a custom adapter that binds view Holder.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int section, int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {

        ArrayList<String> itemsInSection = allData.get(section).getAllItemsInSection();

        String itemName = itemsInSection.get(relativePosition);

        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

        itemViewHolder.itemTitle.setText(itemName);

        // Try to put a image . for sample i set background color in xml layout file
        // itemViewHolder.itemImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01579b"));
    }
```

When I try to replace `itemsInSection` with String which is my requirement I get an error saying cannot resolve .get(int) in line `String itemName = itemsInSection.get(relativePosition);`

How do I resolve it.

Expected Code:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int section, int relativePosition, int absolutePosition) {

        String itemsInSection = allData.get(section).getAllItemsInSection();

        String itemName = itemsInSection.get(relativePosition);  //Error here

        ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

        itemViewHolder.itemTitle.setText(itemName);

        // Try to put a image . for sample i set background color in xml layout file
        // itemViewHolder.itemImage.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#01579b"));
    }
```

Comment: Post the entire code.

Comment: this allData.get(section).getAllItemsInSection(); returns a list, why do you want a String only?

Comment: Because the data from from JSON is String, hence for me to put it in String is better

Comment: Go to this project and see the DataModel class http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/12/sectioned-recyclerview-in-android_1.html || Here they are using `setAllItemsInSection` as ArrayList. But for me the description of List is coming is String from JSON, I don't need ArrayList, but when I change it to String, I find difficulty